# How to check whether a input string is a File name or Folder name using Vbscript

Tags: string, file, input, vbscript, directory

My objective is to find whether the given input is s file name or folder name using Vb script.

For example if user gives "D:\Temp\testfile.docx" then it should navigate to File Related Function,
Similarly if user gives "D:\Temp\" then it should navigate to Folder Related Function.

If there is no straightforward solution, Is there any work around to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether the user input refers to an existing file (.[FileExists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x23stk5t%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)) or folder (.[FolderExists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xc78d8d%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)):

```
If FolderExists(userinp) Then 
   folderaction
Else
   If FileExists(userinp) Then
      fileaction
   Else
      handle bad user input
   End If
End If
```

If that doesn't fit your needs, ask the user to identify folders by always appending "\" and check [Right](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eh8fefz1%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)(userinp, 1).

Comment: This needs modification.  There is no global `FolderExists` function.  You always need a `Scripting.FileSystemObject` instance.

Comment: The code is pseudo code as can be seen by "handle bad user input". I did link to the docs for the functions used.

Answer (score 1):

I created this simple function that should suit your needs:

```
'Return 1 if the provided path is a folder, 2 if it's a file, and -1 if it's neither.
Function GetTypeOfPath(strToTest)
    Dim objFSO : Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If(objFSO.FolderExists(strToTest)) Then
        GetTypeOfPath = 1
    ElseIf(objFSO.FileExists(strToTest)) Then
        GetTypeOfPath = 2
    Else 'neither
        GetTypeOfPath = -1
    End If
End Function
```

You can test it by creating a file "c:\test" and running `MsgBox(GetTypeOfPath("c:\test"))"; it will return 2.  Then delete that file, create a folder "c:\test" and run the same thing; it will return 1.  Then delete that and run it a third time; it will return -1.

Comment: Please edit code or description wrt `GetTypeOfPath = -1`

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner -- elaborate.  I think the description is fine.

Comment: Please edit code or description wrt "third time; it will return 0." Are you pulling my leg?

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner -- my apologies, I didn't know what you were referring to.  I fixed it now.